# Can I move Jenkins to another home folder?

Tags: macos, jenkins

I have installed Jenkins on a MAC OS system and noticed it created a new user(Jenkins).
The problem is that I have many issues with some permissions for that user even if I gave it the right ones.

I just want Jenkins to be installed under my own username home directory:
`/Users/myUsername/jenkins`.

Is there a way to move all the content from `/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home` location to a new one and have it work?

Is this the right documentation for accomplishing this? https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Administering+Jenkins#AdministeringJenkins-Moving%2Fcopying%2Frenamingjobs

Comment: How did you install Jenkins, and what command are you using to run it ?  (The answer to your question depends on the above)

Comment: Jenkins was installed by using Mac OS installed downloaded from the official site. 
I've uninstalled it and reinstalled using `brew install jenkins` and moved all the content from the old place into the new one ( https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Administering+Jenkins )
It seems to be properly working.

Answer (score 1):

Totally! You just need to move the files from your `/User/Shared/Jenkins/Home` to your `/Users/myUsername/jenkins` and modify the `$JENKINS_HOME` to point to your new directory like so:

`$ export JENKINS_HOME=/Users/myUsername/jenkins`, replacing whatever you need to replace.

Comment: On mac its not working. Even after this command home path is not changed.

Comment: You can add the command to your .bashrc before you start jenkins. You can also add it to the jenkins init.d script

Comment: @VenuGopalTewari okay, for me its actually changed, but, I added the `export` earlier to the `~/.bashrc` file before to use the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, in addition to export JENKINS_HOME with the right directory, you need to specify the path here (with Jenkins stopped) :

```
vi /usr/local/opt/jenkins/homebrew.mxcl.jenkins.plist
```

Then launch the right one with this CMD :

```
/usr/bin/java -jar /tmp/jenkins.war --httpListenAddress=0.0.0.0 --httpPort=80
```